# how to setup leaaflet marker opacity?

Tags: javascript

im working with map api. i try to hide the marker if the zoom level is below 15 and show the marker if the zoom level more than 15.
here are my code :

```
const markerS = L.marker([0, 0], {icon: start}).addTo(mymap);
const api_url = 'json.php'
        async function getjson() {
        const response = await fetch(api_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        const start = (data[0])
        const zoom = mymap.getZoom();
        markerS.setLatLng([start.latitude, start.longtitude]);
        if(zoom > 15) {
        markerS.style.display == "block"
            } else {
        markerS.style.display = "none"
            }     
        }
```

but the if logic doesn't work. the console.log show "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')
at getjson"

how i can fix this?

Comment: What is `markerS`?

Comment: for marker  on map, i try to show the marker if the zoom level is more than 15. any suggestion?

Comment: Your question lacks a MCVE - please edit one into the question so we can see at least what sort of variable `markerS` is

Comment: okey i already edit my question, i forgot to mention variable markers im sorry hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet marker instances are not DOM elements - they don't have a `.style` property. They do, however have a [`setOpacity`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#marker-setopacity) method.

Change

```
markerS.style.display == "block"
markerS.style.display = "none"
```

to

```
markerS.setOpacity(100);
markerS.setOpacity(0);
```

respectively.

Comment: wow, how did you know im using leaflet api? you must very experienced in javascript, i envy you. i already test your code and it works like charm. thankyou so much for your guidance :-)

Comment: I have never done anything with Leaflet before at all, I only looked up the documentation just now after googling `L.marker`.